# Таблетки и пилюли: синонимы или нет?

Tags: синонимы

Слово "пилюли" у меня почему-то больше ассоциируется с детскими книжками. Но, интересно, это то же самое, что таблетки, или нет?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, это несколько разные вещи. 
Тем не менее слова всегда даются как синонимы, причем довольно близкие.

Что же касается значения, то пилюлями - под конец активного существования слова - стали назвать всяческие таблетки, любой формы и вида, и вручную приготовленные и нет, и даже дражжевидные с "начинкой". Вот в отношении последнего, есть у меня смутное подозрение, что изначально оно тоже так было, пилюльки изначально вполне могли быть "двуслойными", с начинкой и оболочкой. Но подтвердить не могу.

Comment: Да проще все, "пилюля" - в переводе с латыни - "шарик"."Таблетка",вероятно пришло из французского, значений много, происходит от латинского "табула"- "доска","пластина,пластинка",очевидно, что-то плоское,небольшое.То есть названия эти - отражают форму, а совсем не начинки и оболочки.

Comment: >Да проще все,   
  
Что именно?

>"пилюля" - в переводе с латыни - "шарик".  
  
Да.

>"Таблетка",вероятно пришло из французского,   
  
Да.  
  
Все так, но это никак не опровергает и не подтверждает сказанного мной и другими участниками. Мы говорим не столько о этимологии, сколько о семантике слов в русском языке, причем я ввел в рассмотрение еще и временной аспект, т.к. предположительно значение слова пилюля несколько менялось со временем.

Comment: to @behemothus 

ПИЛЮЛЯ лат. pilula, уменьшит, от pila, шарик. а) Лекарство, в виде шарика...
(Источник: «Объяснение 25000 иностранных слов, вошедших в употребление в русский язык, с означением их корней». Михельсон А.Д.)
           Хотя без французского и тут не обошлось.Скорее всего, наше "пилюля" вошла в обиход из <pilule>фр. и правы Вы, а не малоизвестный Михельсон А.Д.1865. Но с начинками, покрытиями или без таковых "пилюля" означает форму, в которую облечено лекарственное средство.

Answer (score 6):

Таблетка - плоская, а пилюля в форме шарика, покрытого оболочкой.

Comment: табле́тка

1. ж. устар.
1) Тонкая пластинка - обычно из слоновой кости - для записи чего-л. на память.

2) Дощечка, пластинка - обычно из обожженной глины - для письма.

2. ж.
Маленькая твердая лепешечка, шарик из прессованного лекарственного порошка определенной дозировки.

ПИЛЮЛЯ
лат. pilula, уменьшит, от pila, шарик. а) Лекарство, в виде шарика. b) Неприятность.

(Источник: «Объяснение 25000 иностранных слов, вошедших в употребление в русский язык, с означением их корней». Михельсон А.Д., 1865)

Это из старых словарей.
А есть таблетки - электронные приборы, таблетки-украшения и т.д.

Comment: А еще фасон шапочки - таблетка, именно потому, что плоская.

Answer (score 2):

Пилюля - это "таблетка", сделанная вручную. Аптекарь смешивал лекарства, скатывал их в шарик и выдавал больному. Чтобы пилюля была не такой горькой, в ингредиенты мог быть добавлен подсластитель.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что сейчас слово "пилюли" почти вышло из употребления. Ни разу не слышала, чтобы кому-то их назначили. Часто слышу такие наименования: таблетки, капсулы (оболочка, а в ней порошок или гранулы), порошок, гранулы ("шарики", например, гомеопатические), иногда еще драже (покрытые оболочкой, плоские, с прослойкой, чаще относится к витаминам). 
  Но все зависит от контекста. В каком-то случае это будут синонимы, а в каком-то нет. Это относится и к пилюлям.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное всё-таки разница в форме. Все остальное — догадки без подтверждения.

В Вики я обнаружил, что пилюли — это только от 0,1 до 0,5 г, что меньше — гранулы, что больше — болюсы. 
Но это не очень похоже на строгое медицинское определение, как и само разделение по форме. Поэтому, думаю, в медицинской практике вполне можно считать синонимами, а в быту искать разницу смысла нет, ибо всё субъективно.